# Preview html in browser like it is displayed in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: browser, webkit, wkhtmltopdf

Is there any browsers that use the same engine (webkit 2.2.4 I believe) to display CSS as wkhtmltopdf does?

I am trying to create a print document and it looks perfect on newest Chrome/Firefox but it looks totally broken when i print it via wkhtmltopdf.

I have used prefixing to help me along this journey, but now I have come across something weird that probably requires some CSS hacks to fix and in that case, I would like to have an easier debugging tool.

**What I am trying to achieve here is** do debug the print in a browser using the same engine as wkhtmltopdf, so I don't have to print the file and open it each time I do some changes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems Safari versions from 8 and down looks the same as wkhtmltopdf. 
So maybe [webkit 538.35.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history)? This works for me for now by using Browserstack.

The closest Google Chrome version i could find was using webkit 537.36 - [Chrome version 27.0.1453, before going over to Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history). I have not tried this out.